# Determining limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-without-lhopital

If  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{1^2}  + \frac{1}{2^2} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{n^2} \right)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

If $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{1^3\cdot 2^3}  + \frac{1}{3^3\cdot 4^3} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{n^3\cdot(n+1)^3} \right)=S$$

How to determine $S$?

I tried making a general pattern

~     $ \frac{n+1-n}{n^3\cdot(n+1)^3}   $ = $ \frac{1}{n^3\cdot(n+1)^2}  - \frac{1}{n^2\cdot(n+1)^3}   $   this is not giving me any cancellation of terms neither any involvement of above series

Comment: What have you tried

Comment: What is the connection between these series?

Comment: Perhaps you may want to work with this first: $$
\Big(\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)^3=\Big(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)^3=
\frac{1}{n^3}+3\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{n+1}-3\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** $$\dfrac{1}{n^3(n+1)^3}=6\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)-3\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{n^3}-\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right).$$ Now, telescope.

Comment: After telescoping and taking limit, I got $10-\pi^2.$ Let me know if you need any additional clarification regarding this.

Comment: This nice answer reminded me [this article](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/pi10.pdf) by Noam Elkies.